# Python Beautiful Soup Parse First Href in Each Div

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Given the following code:

```
# import the module
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import re

masterURL = 'http://www.metrolyrics.com/top100.html'
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(masterURL).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')




for div in soup.findAll('ul', {'class': 'song-list'}):
    for span in div:
        for link in span:
            for a in link:
                print(a)
```

I can parse multiple divs, and i get a result as follows :

[image]

My question is instead of getting the full contents of the div how can I only return the highlighted portion, the URL of the Href?

Comment: `a.get('href')` you try this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You need to specify the right `class` to fetch the urls connected to it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

masterURL = 'http://www.metrolyrics.com/top100.html'
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(masterURL).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')

for div in soup.find_all(class_='subtitle'):
    print(div.get("href"))
```

Output:

```
http://www.metrolyrics.com/charles-goose-lyrics.html
http://www.metrolyrics.com/param-singh-lyrics.html
http://www.metrolyrics.com/westlife-lyrics.html
http://www.metrolyrics.com/luis-fonsi-lyrics.html
http://www.metrolyrics.com/grease-lyrics.html
http://www.metrolyrics.com/shanti-dope-lyrics.html
```

and so on ---

Answer (score 0):

```
if 'href' in a.attrs:
     a.attrs['href']
```

this will give you what you need.